# Chrome Extension manifest v3: how to inject react app with isolated antd styles?

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, antd

I have a chrome extension, which was working fine during manifest v2. It is a react app using `antd` styles. I am trying to migrate it to manifest v3 but when antd styles are added to app, since I am injecting the app in websites `DOM`, the styles gets applied to everything in the websites aswell.

I have tried isolating the same with the help of `react-frame-component`, but haven't been able to compile `antd` styles to a single file which I can add in `content-scripts` in order to be accessible by the frame component.

I am trying with `webpack` configuration but I am not very well versed with customised compilation and tried with `vite` aswell, since they have some support for chrome extension through `crxjs`, but haven't found any example with `antd` compilation.

If anyone might have any resource to refer to, then it would be very helpful.

I tried customised `webpack` and `vite` config, in order to compile all `antd` styles to a single file, so that I can add that file in the `content-scripts` which makes it eligible for extension to request. Manifest v3 doesn't allow calling 3rd party sites, otherwise I could have used `CDN` links to `antd` styles.

Comment: There's no need to add the styles to manifest.json if you use a frame. And an even worse idea if you don't because these styles could clash with the page styles. The frame can point its src to an html file in your extension which can be a separate entry point in your bundler so it'll take care of everything.

Comment: That's what we were doing before manifest V3, but not now you cannot load any other domain from your extension. Content scripts will let the resource be available for the frame to access it, without chrome causing issues. Manifest json will most probably be pointing to the file containing the styles, which I can request and fetch in frame later on.

Comment: I mean web_accessible_resources iframe, which didn't change in ManifestV3.

Comment: try to use shadow root element and append the whole app to it.